# Meteor as a pure Application Server

Tags: meteor, ddp, demeteorizer

I want to use MeteorJS server as a pure Application Server, which means, I only want it to handle Publications and Server Methods. I want to have a dedicated server to serve the HTML, CSS and Javascript bundle to the client but the application would use another server to handle all the DDP connections.

Is there a non-hacky and reliable way to do this?

Would this approach help to scale an application, by removing the static content out of the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor is built to do this by providing the capacity to set a separate DDP server as well as .js and .css files with cache busting names.

The DDP server is specified by setting an environment variable with `export` or when you run your built app.  Like this:

```
DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL=http://ddp.yourdomain.com node /yourpath/main.js
```

There is a [tutorial to achieve this with Cloudflare](https://meteorhacks.com/cloudflare-meets-meteor.html) and [a gist that explains how to do this with NGINX](https://gist.github.com/dweldon/6148634).